# How can I configure my computer to run an AppleScript at a specific time? Caveat: without using iCal

Tags: applescript, macos

Since upgrading to Lion, I have seen a sleight decrease of productivity when it comes to using iCal. As a result, I am trying alternatives such as BusyCal. The application seems great, however I cant set an alarm to run a script as I could in iCal.

Hence, I want to become independent from iCal and have an AppleScript run everyday without having to keep iCal running. Any idea of how to do this?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can run a cronjob using [crontab.](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/crontab.1.html) 
So basically, to run a cronjob, you will need to type `nano ~/crontab` in Terminal. This will create a new file called "crontab" in your home folder, and open up a simple text editor in Terminal. Type:

`* * * * * osascript ~/Desktop/theScriptToBeExecuted.applescript`

This will run an AppleScript named "theScriptToBeExecuted.applescript" located on your desktop, every minute. The five "*" before the `osascript` command specify the time. Here's a table to show you what each field stands for:

```
*     *     *   *    *        command to be executed
-     -     -   -    -
|     |     |   |    |
|     |     |   |    +----- day of week (0 - 6) (Sunday=0)
|     |     |   +------- month (1 - 12)
|     |     +--------- day of        month (1 - 31)
|     +----------- hour (0 - 23)
+------------- min (0 - 59)
```

So to run the same command at one minute past midnight (00:01) of every day of the month, of every day of the week, type this in the file:

`1 0 * * * osascript ~/Desktop/theScriptToBeExecuted.applescript`

If you need more info, check out [this article on cron.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron)

To save the file that you're working on, type <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> (exits), then <kbd>Y</kbd> (tells Terminal that you do want to save the file), then <kbd>Enter</kbd> Now type at the prompt `cron ~/crontab` This tells cron that it should be looking at the crontab file, if your file is named "crontab" in your home folder.

Another alternative is [Cronnix](http://code.google.com/p/cronnix/) It's a GUI for crontab.

Script Timer is similar, but it runs specified AppleScripts at specified times. It's a little easier to use, but it costs $12. I would recommend just going with Cronnix (free) or crontab (also free!)

Comment: how would i use that utility to do what I am trying to do?

Comment: Do you want to add the condition: without using terminal?

Comment: No, I'm fine with using the terminal. I'd like to add the condition: without spending a great deal of time learning a command line utility.

Comment: @segfault Sorry, I was typing it up and I posted the answer before I was done.

Comment: @segfault NP! Glad to help!

Answer (score 3):

In recent versions of OS X `launchd` is preferred to `cron`. Here's an excerpt from `man crontab` under Mavericks:

> Darwin note: Although cron(8) and crontab(5) are officially supported under Darwin, their functionality has been absorbed into launchd(8), which provides a more flexible way of automatically executing commands.

You can control `launchd` using the built-in `launchctl` but many people (including me) use a GUI called [Lingon](http://www.peterborgapps.com/lingon/).

UPDATE: I now use [LaunchControl](http://www.soma-zone.com/LaunchControl/) instead of Lingon. It's a lot more powerful, though the interface is more complicated.