# How to run AppleScript in a Crontab?

Tags: macos, mac, cron

I am using OS X 10.11.5, I have a crontab file under '/tmp/crontab', in which it contains:

```
01 10 * * * /Users/Jhon/Desktop/somescript.scpt
```

When I run `crontab -l` I get output as `no crontab for Jhon`

Any suggestion what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: Read here: http://alvinalexander.com/mac-os-x/mac-osx-startup-crontab-launchd-jobs

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I configure my computer to run an AppleScript at a specific time? Caveat: without using iCal](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/24862/how-can-i-configure-my-computer-to-run-an-applescript-at-a-specific-time-caveat)

Comment: [This answer](http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/24863/119271) explains how to create a crontab

Answer (score 2):

Apple recommends using `launchd` which actually runs cron tasks for MacOS. You can still use `crontab -e` to edit your crontab, but if you want a one-liner:

```
(crontab -l 2>/dev/null; echo "01 10 * * * osascript /Users/Jhon/Desktop/somescript.scpt") | crontab - ; crontab -l
```

See this answer for much more useful details:

[How can I configure my computer to run an AppleScript at a specific time? Caveat: without using iCal](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/24862/how-can-i-configure-my-computer-to-run-an-applescript-at-a-specific-time-caveat/24863#24863)

Comment: It's important to note that [`cron` has been deprecated in favor of `launchd`](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/266836/119271).  It's a good idea to start migrating to the new framework.

Comment: Oh dear Apple. Strike 1 against programmers.