# How do I restart the cron service on OSX?

Tags: macos, bash, launchd

```
ProductName:    Mac OS X
ProductVersion: 10.11.6
BuildVersion:   15G31

$ sudo cron restart
cron: cron already running, pid: 257`
```

None of the answers in here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10193788/restarting-cron-after-changing-crontab-file seem to apply to OSX. Well the one above is the closest one but it appears to be just telling me that cron is running so I don't have to worry about restarting it. Which isn't the point of restarting something.

How do I stop and restart the cron service on a Mac?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve by restarting cron?

Comment: I'm trying to achieve the restarting of cron; I see no harm in confirming that the service has absolutely positively seen the new crontab files

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The cron daemon is managed with launchctl.

If you insist on restarting it, you have to unload and load the respective launch daemon:

```
sudo launchctl unload /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.vix.cron.plist
sudo launchctl load /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.vix.cron.plist
```

**But: adding or removing arbitrary crontabs shouldn't require a reload of the daemon to enable or disable them.**

The above launch daemon plist contains a *Watch Directory* directive which detects (crontab) file creation and deletion or modified dates and "instructs" cron respectively.

Comment: /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.vix.cron.plist: Operation not permitted while System Integrity Protection is engaged

Comment: would cron show up in `launchctl list`? when I load cron as you showed it says its already loaded. and when I do `launchctl list | grep cron` its empty.

Answer (score 5):

```
sudo pkill -f cron
```

The LaunchDaemon has a keepalive section in it that will immediately restart it.

Comment: Please use code formatting for, well, code and shell commands. It makes it easier to read/recognize and also helps people with screen readers.

Comment: Programmers use screen readers? Ummm, OK

Comment: You might be surprised. Anyway, most visitors here ain‘t programmers.

Answer (score 2):

From the `cron` man page:

> The cron utility is launched by launchd(8) when it sees the existence
>   of /etc/crontab or files in /usr/lib/cron/tabs.  There should be no
>   need to start it manually.  See
>   /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.vix.cron.plist for details.

So, interstingly enough, `cron` is launched by `launchd`.  However, according to `man crontab`

> (Darwin note: Although cron(8) and crontab(5) are
>   officially supported under Darwin, their functionality has been
>   absorbed into launchd(8), which provides a more flexible way of
>   automatically executing commands. See launchctl(1) for more
>   information.)

So, `cron` which is launched by `launchd`, has been deprecated for `launchd`.  Using `cron` is like wrapping bacon in bacon because you want bacon flavored bacon.

As far as restarting `cron`, there is no need.  Once it sees a `crontab` file, it will automatically launch the job.

However, it's highly advisable that you [start scheduling jobs using `launchd.`](http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=2012073000433650)

Comment: I don't trust computers to see changes to files all the time so I'd like to confirm that it has the new files loaded by restarting

Comment: -1, answers the question by saying "don't worry about it"

Comment: If you type `crontab -l`; whatever is there is loaded.