# How do I kill a currently running cron job on macOS High Sierra

Tags: macos, cron

Edit: This question is NOT a duplicate of [How do I restart the cron service on OSX?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/266835/how-do-i-restart-the-cron-service-on-osx) as I explained in point 3...

I am busy trying to test a process that's started using the `crontab` on macOS High Sierra. I cannot seem to kill it easily so that I can make a change and re-run it to test my change.

I can tell what the `cron` process is doing as I am logging the output/process to a text file and `tailing -f` it in terminal, anything I have tried hasn't stopped the job.

Here's what I have tried:

1. Listing processes (aux) via `ps aux | grep cron` doesn't list anything that looks like my currently running `cronjob`.
2. `ps -ef | grep cron` shows three processes but none of them are the job itself as far as I can tell, list shown below:

   ```
   0   41453     1   0 12:55pm ??         0:00.01 /usr/sbin/cron
   503 38049 37800   0 12:04pm ttys002    0:00.24 tail -f cron-test.txt
   503 42548 38511   0  1:24pm ttys003    0:00.00 grep --color=auto --exclude-dir=.bzr --exclude-dir=CVS --exclude-dir=.git --exclude-dir=.hg --exclude-dir=.svn cron
   ```
3. I tried unloading/loading the launch daemon ([How do I restart the cron service on OSX?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/266835/how-do-i-restart-the-cron-service-on-osx)) which `cron` is run through but, trying to do this requires that System Integrity Protection be disabled. Doing this requires me to reboot in recovery mode which is pointless, I may as well then just reboot the Mac everytime.

`crontab -l` output in case its relevant.

```
*/44 * * * * cd /Users/my_user_name/Development/Sites/website-handover-dev/web && \
    ./cron-test.sh && \
    time ./cron-test.sh >> /Users/my_user_name/Development/Sites/website-handover-dev/web/cron-test.txt 2>&1
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I restart the cron service on OSX?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/266835/how-do-i-restart-the-cron-service-on-osx)

Comment: Edited the title, apologies slight error - Need to stop the currently running job

Comment: Simply, remove the `crontab` entry or entries from the user's `crontab`. `cron` wakes every minute, checks if a entry needs to be run, and also checks the modification time of a crontab,. Thus the crontab entry will be stopped if removed. There is no need to stop and restart cron.

Comment: How long does the `cron-test.sh` script run?

Comment: @nohillside - more than 20 minutes (Contact API for data and does several other items. sh Script runs a Drupal Drush command)

Comment: ? Why would `grep cron` catch the process name? Wouldn't the process that `cron` started run under its own name? Also - are you using the same userid for your commands that the crontab is using?