# "Full Disk Access" for backup tool running as cron job

Tags: backup, command-line, mojave

I'm running a command-line backup tool (duplicity) as a cron job. But in Mojave, there is a new user data protection feature called "Full Disk Access" (part of the TCC access control framework) that prevents duplicity from accessing certain user-owned files.

How do I whitelist this command-line tool? Since it runs as a cron job, adding Terminal.app to the whitelist won't work. I tried adding the duplicity binary to the whitelist in `System Preferences > Security & Privacy > Full Disk Access`, but that changed nothing. I also tried running duplicity manually to see if anything would show up in that whitelist, but nothing did.

Edit: the answer to [this question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/332673/what-and-how-does-macos-mojave-implement-to-restrict-applications-access-to-pers) is not a solution. I clearly explained that I have already tried whitelisting to no avail.

Comment: I don't think cron jobs use launchd, so I haven't tried whitelisting that. But I could certainly run duplicity using launchd, so I'll try that next.

Comment: Misread. Cron is its own process. Try adding that. `/usr/sbin/cron`?

Comment: `cron` isn't "attached" to Terminal the way a standalone command would be, so allowing Terminal won't have any effect.  Try `launchd` as [`cron` has been deprecated](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/266836/119271).

Comment: I am using a `launchd` service instead of `cron` and running in the same issue. It's unclear how to whitelist a specific launchd service into Full Disk Access.

Comment: This really is not a duplicate of that thread, since the process for interactive and GUI apps does not work for automated scripts / binaries. If anything, it's closer to a duplicate of [this question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/338213/), but the listed answer for that one is not really an answer.

Comment: This is not a duplicate... and to echo other comments, to allow a script run via `cron` to access files, like `~/Pictures/`, then you need to add `cron` to System Preferences > Security & Privacy > Full Disk Access.

Comment: see https://n8henrie.com/2018/11/how-to-give-full-disk-access-to-a-binary-in-macos-mojave/

Comment: Agreed; this is not a dupe.