# change default editor for command line tasks?

Tags: text-editor, environment-variables, cron

I want to create a `cron` job. Launching a terminal window, and entering `crontab -e` opens my current `crontab`, but opens it in the editor `vi`. I would prefer to use the `nano` editor.

How do I configure my system (Mojave) to launch `nano` instead of `vi`?

Comment: `cron` has been [deprecated for `launchd`](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/266836/119271) You should be using that instead.

Comment: @Allan: Yep, I've used `launchd`, but `cron` is just simpler to use. Deprecated?... we'll see. The deprecation was announced in 2005 (IIRC), yet...

Comment: @Allan: But I do get your point. I feel that my subject line was misleading, so I've changed that.

Comment: “vi” is the only editor guaranteed to be on a UNIX system and quite powerful so worth learning.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen: Gosh, really?

Comment: Yes.  Naturally depends on what skill set you are aiming for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The editor that is launched when you enter `crontab -e` at the command line is set in an ***environment variable***. Specifically, the default editor that is launched in your terminal window is controlled by the *environment variable* labeled **VISUAL**, or **$VISUAL**. You can see all of the environment variables for the shell you're using by typing `env` at the command prompt; e.g.:

```
My-MacBook-15:~ seamus$ env
TERM_PROGRAM=Apple_Terminal
SHELL=/bin/bash
TERM=xterm-256color
TMPDIR=/var/folders/8_/s3jxzj5150s9f3d3y5k4wzdr0000gp/T/
Apple_PubSub_Socket_Render=/private/tmp/com.apple.launchd.f9meUexEfE/Render
TERM_PROGRAM_VERSION=421.1
TERM_SESSION_ID=CECBC621-33BB-45FD-96E3-B414DBE99F65
USER=seamus
SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/private/tmp/com.apple.launchd.LVyDWNJZbD/Listeners
PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Applications/VMware Fusion.app/Contents/Public:/opt/X11/bin
PWD=/Users/seamus
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
XPC_FLAGS=0x0
XPC_SERVICE_NAME=0
SHLVL=1
HOME=/Users/seamus
LOGNAME=seamus
DISPLAY=/private/tmp/com.apple.launchd.tzdryqvBdL/org.macosforge.xquartz:0
SECURITYSESSIONID=186a7
_=/usr/bin/env
```

You may note, as in the above example, that the **VISUAL** *environment variable* is not included in this list. This only means that for your current username, the **VISUAL** *environment variable* has not been changed from the system's default. You can confirm this (or check the value of the the **VISUAL** *environment variable*) in a compact manner as follows:

```
My-MacBook-15:~ seamus$ echo $VISUAL

My-MacBook-15:~ seamus$
```

The blank line indicates that no value for `$VISUAL` has been set for this user, and the system default will be used.

#### CHANGING THE DEFAULT EDITOR FOR THE CURRENT SESSION:

To set the **VISUAL** *environment variable* so that `nano` is launched as the default editor for all editing tasks initiated from a terminal window for this user, simply set the *environment variable* as follows:

```
My-MacBook-15:~ seamus$ VISUAL=nano
My-MacBook-15:~ seamus$ export VISUAL
```

Or, if you prefer:

```
My-MacBook-15:~ seamus$ export VISUAL=nano
```

You can verify this setting as follows:

```
My-MacBook-15:~ seamus$ echo $VISUAL
nano
My-MacBook-15:~ seamus$
```

And that will do it! From this point forward (until your shell or your system is re-started), any time an editing task is launched from a command in a terminal window for this user, `nano` will be used instead of the system default. And of course the system's default editor will be restored when the system (or the shell) is re-started. If you don't wish to perform a re-start to restore the default editor, simply specify `vi` as the editor:

```
My-MacBook-15:~ seamus$ export VISUAL=vi
```

#### CHANGING THE DEFAULT EDITOR TO PERSIST ACROSS ALL SESSIONS:

To change the default editor ***permanently*** (that is, to persist across re-starts) is also easily accomplished. Simply create a *hidden* file in the user's *home* directory (`~/`), and set the **VISUAL** *environment variable* in it, all accomplished conveniently in a single line:

```
My-MacBook-15:~ seamus$ echo export VISUAL=nano >> ~/.bash_profile
```