# Stop macOS from accessing external drive at night

Tags: macos, hard-drive, spotlight

I have Mac Mini Mid 2011 with macOS 10.13.5 with a data drive. When I wake up at night, the drive is running. I ran `fs_usage` and was surprised to find macOS accessing the drive a lot.

How do I stop macOS from spinning the drive, except when accessed by a human, or at least not at certain hours when I sleep? Can Spotlight/macOS be configured to lay off the drive at night?

```
00:01:10  fsgetpath         /Volumes/FOOBAR  0.000022   mds
00:01:10  statfs64          /Volumes/FOOBAR  0.000015   Finder
00:01:10  getattrlist       /Volumes/FOOBAR  0.000017   Finder
00:08:59  getattrlist       /Volumes/FOOBAR  0.000019   backupd-help
00:39:54  getattrlist       /Volumes/FOOBAR  0.000031   diskspaced
00:39:54  getattrlist       /Volumes/FOOBAR  0.000081   diskspaced
00:39:54  statfs64          /Volumes/FOOBAR  0.000014   diskspaced
01:08:47  getattrlist       /Volumes/FOOBAR  0.000017   backupd-help
02:08:35  getattrlist       /Volumes/FOOBAR  0.000020   backupd-help
03:08:40  getattrlist       /Volumes/FOOBAR  0.000033   backupd-help
04:04:09  getattrlist       /Volumes/FOOBAR  0.000019   fontworker
04:04:39  getattrlist       /Volumes/FOOBAR  0.000015   fontworker
04:11:01  getattrlist       /Volumes/FOOBAR  0.000032   backupd-help
05:11:56  getattrlist       /Volumes/FOOBAR  0.000052   backupd-help
06:05:23  getattrlist       /Volumes/FOOBAR  0.000030   backupd-help
06:33:52  getattrlist       /Volumes/FOOBAR  0.000017   fontworker
06:34:15  getattrlist       /Volumes/FOOBAR  0.000020   fontworker
06:34:48  getattrlist       /Volumes/FOOBAR  0.000014   fontworker
06:36:23  fsgetpath         /Volumes/FOOBAR  0.000012   revisiond
06:36:23  fsctl             /Volumes/FOOBAR  0.000010   revisiond
06:36:23  getattrlist       /Volumes/FOOBAR  0.000023   revisiond
06:36:23  statfs64          /Volumes/FOOBAR  0.000011   revisiond
06:36:23  lstat64           /Volumes/FOOBAR  0.000010   revisiond
06:36:23  lstat64           /Volumes/FOOBAR  0.000008   revisiond
06:36:23  statfs64          /Volumes/FOOBAR  0.000007   revisiond
06:36:23  getattrlist       /Volumes/FOOBAR  0.000012   deleted
06:36:23  statfs64          /Volumes/FOOBAR  0.000005   deleted
06:36:23  lstat64           /Volumes/FOOBAR  0.000009   deleted
(...)
06:36:23  getattrlist       /Volumes/FOOBAR  0.000055   AOSHeartbeat
06:36:25  statfs64          /Volumes/FOOBAR  0.000006   df
06:36:30  HFS_update /Volumes/FOOBAR/..V100/../db.sqlite-wal launchd
```

Comment: Is "Put hard disks to sleep when possible" enabled in Energy Saver prefpane?

Comment: Is "Power Nap" disabled (Energy Saver prefpane as well)?

Comment: Ah, right, PowerNap in Mini is only from late 2012 onwards

Comment: From looking at the timestamps it always wakes up a few minutes after the hour. Are there are other devices on your network which might send a WOL (wake on LAN) signal?

Comment: @nohillside: I can't imagine what that would be.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the best solution would be **mounting** and **unmounting** the drive to completely ensure no activity from the OS or any other rogue processes.

There is an already built solution that is **paid**: 
Following this [guide](https://www.dssw.co.uk/blog/2017-06-12-schedule-drive-mount-on-macos/) can help with more advanced settings how to unmount and mount the drive.

A free **Solution would be combining**

[Apple Script disk mounting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29332873/os-x-applescript-to-check-if-drive-mounted-and-mount-it-if-not) with [Time scheduling to execute script](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/24862/how-can-i-configure-my-computer-to-run-an-applescript-at-a-specific-time-caveat)

Comment: That's actually quite an effective workaround, at least until a root cause and proper solution is found.

Comment: I'd be really curious to see a custom AppleScript that does that, as potential other solutions that i'd probably use it for would be a time-machine drive, but leaving it on at night for backups and turning it off in the day time...

Comment: I simply added `diskutil (un)mountdisk /dev/disk2s2` to my crontab. Hack-ish, but it will work until I find a proper solution.

Comment: This would be very effective coupled with sleep settings and power nap settings and locating Time Machine data off the drives in question.