# Applescript to turn HDDs off during day, and back on at night

Tags: hard-drive, applescript, backup, time-machine, mount

I figure I should ask my first question,

I'm curious to see how an **Applescript** could control my HDD that my TimeMachine is backed-up on  to un-mount during the day, and back on before the scheduled backup starts would work.

A bit of research has found:

[Applescript to check if drive is mounted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29332873/os-x-applescript-to-check-if-drive-mounted-and-mount-it-if-not)

and

[Running an Applescript at a specific time](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/24862/how-can-i-configure-my-computer-to-run-an-applescript-at-a-specific-time-caveat)

I think this could be very powerful with use of [Time Machine Editor](https://tclementdev.com/timemachineeditor/)

Especially for anyone with a HDD wanting to preserve active hours.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: TimeMachine runs hourly, so if you unmont you will get an error message within the hour.

Comment: Anyway, you already have all the details in the links you've included in the question. What have you tried, how did it not work as expected?

Comment: The Time Machine editor allows scheduling of the backups only to occur after 1AM, which cancels out any unmount error messages. I have tried setting up a crontab with a diskutil unmount of my hdd, but I honesly think the lack of sleep may just be the issue. I'll have another go in the morning

Comment: What’s the gain and/or benefit of doing this?   This seems like a lot of work to overcome a non-issue.

Comment: Lack of sleep for you or for your computer? You can still run scripts from Calendar events which can be configured to repeat on a custom schedule. i have several Automator workflows programmed into a calendar which are triggered on a daily basis. If you need help, let us know.